# How to refresh rangeslider in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use jquery-1.10.2 and jquery.mobile-1.3.2
And
$(".rs").rangeslider();
$(".rs").rangeslider('refresh');
not working when i try to add rangeslider by js.
Error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slider' of undefined

Sliders are not refresh correctly too by .slider(). There is no number field after refresh.

Is there problem in jquerymobile api for refreshing sliders or my mistake?

Comment: If I use slider refresh for each sliders in rangeslider then number inputs not display.

Comment: This helps to refresh number input for slider: $('#content').html('<input data-type="range" name="r6a" id="r6a" min="0" max="100" value="0">');
$("input").slider();
$("input").textinput();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Range slider enhancement methods aren't functioning as they should. Unlike toggle switch, which can be enhance using `.slider()`.

To enhance slider dynamically inserted, you need to call

```
$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cXUjc/)**